# what's wrong? "add class when empty" script

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, show-hide

I've got the following script, but `addClass` is not called on the `li` "spect" when `div` "tab2" is empty.

Can anybody help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
if($("div#tab2").html() != "")
{
$("li#spect").addClass("leftmax");
} 
});
</script>



<div class="content_container">

<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#tab1">TAB1</a></li>
<li id="spect"><a href="#tab2">TAB2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">TAB3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content"><h2>title<h2></div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content"></div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content"><h2>title<h2></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: change your `!=` to `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you only want to add the class when div#tab2 is empty. If so, then you had a logic error in your comparison operator. Do this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    if ($("div#tab2").html() == "") {
        $("li#spect").addClass("leftmax");
    } 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you are testing for "not empty". Try:

```
if($("div#tab2").html() == "")
```